# Should Dynamodb apply single table design instead of multiple table design when the entities are not relational

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Let’s assume there are mainly 3 tables for the current database.

Pkey = partition key

Admin 
-id(Pkey), username, email, createdAt,UpdatedAt

Banner 
-id(Pkey), isActive, createdAt, caption

News 
-id(Pkey), createdAt, isActive, title, message

None of the above tables have relation with other tables, and more tables will be required in the future(I think most of it also don’t have the relation with other tables).

According to the aws document

```
You should maintain as few tables as possible in a DynamoDB application.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html

So I was considering the need to combine these 3 tables into a single table.

Should I start to use a single table from now on, or keep using multiple tables for the database?
If using a single table, how should I design the table schema?

Comment: NoSQL data modeling could be a field of study unto itself.  Entire books are written on the subject.  To get started quickly, I'd highly recommend watching this intro talk on DDB data modeling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE

Comment: This question has been asked and answered multiple times here on SO but I just want to call out one thing:  "application" can mean multiple things: for sufficiently complex examples, where the design matters most, you may have a service that deals with administration and authorization and a separate service that deals with news and perhaps banners: in that case, having separate resources per service makes the most sense

Comment: The meta-point being that you should aim to understand the rationale behind these recommendations instead of blindingly following them. Like others have said, with DynamoDB you want to optimize for your access patterns. Start from that and design accordingly but don't over engineer and don't try too hard to fit a square peg into a round hole

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database, hence you design your schema specifically to make the most common and important queries as fast and as inexpensive as possible. Your data structures are tailored to the specific requirements of your business use cases.

When designing a data model for your DynamoDB Table, you should start from the access patterns of your data that would in turn inform the relation (or lack thereof) among them.

Two interesting resources that would help you get started are [From SQL to NoSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.html) and [NoSQL Design for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html), both part of the AWS Developer Documentation of DynamoDB.

In your specific example, based on the questions you're trying to answer (i.e. use case & access patterns), you could either work with only the Partition Key or more likely, benefit from the usage of composite Sort Keys / Sort Key overloading as described in [Best Practices for Using Sort Keys to Organize Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html).

Update, add example table design to get you started:
[image: Table Aggregated View]

Comment: So u mean I can keep my multiple tables design?

Comment: I mean you can use only one table.

Comment: Can u also provide some example of how I design my single table using my current table?thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer, please keep in mind that this is only an example to get you started. As I said in my original answer, without knowing how you'll access the data there's no way for me to create a good table schema.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the reason of not using type (admin, news)as partition key, u use random id instead

Comment: Uniqueness of items in DynamoDB is given by either PK or the combination of PK+SK. If you use "admin" (or "news", or "banner") as PK then you can only have one of each and that's it. In this way you can have as many admins, news, banners as you want as long as they have different uuid.

Comment: @Andre.IDK -- using "admin", "news", "banner" as PK is an anti-pattern; you could end up with unbalanced access really quickly as the cardinality of each of these categories will likely be very different

Comment: I actually meant SK, not PK (look at the table in my answer). Sorry for the typo!